# CSS Specificity - can't get to the point

Tags: html, css

Guys can anyone tell me why I can't remove the `list-style-type` from the `<ul>` below using the specificity defined below the html.

```
<footer><!-- this is where the footer starts-->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_2">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <strong>
                            <a href="#">test</a>
                        </strong>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Why </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Get Started</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Customers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Careers</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

footer ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I've also tried `footer div div ul {}` but I can't seem to address the `ul` element.

Comment: What you have works. http://jsfiddle.net/uHYkA/  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css class needs to be called `.footer ul {...}`, and footer has to actually use it: `<footer class="footer">` - because in IE6, and any other browser that doesn't understand HTML5 tags, `<footer>` is renamed to `<div>` by whichever solution you are using, so the css selector would not apply any longer...

**UPDATE:** check in any browser developer tools if anything is overriding your style, or try forcing it with `list-style-type: none !important;`

Comment: Its my understanding that you can just reference html tags by naming them in a CSS file... ive never had any problems doing it before so this ones strange!

Comment: sorry... i should say that i have just tried defining the class in both the css script and applying it to the html like you've said but its not worked

Comment: But if the footer *has* a class of `footer` then in the CSS it'd have to be `.footer {...}` anyway; so it *still* wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidThomas: he wants to style ul, not the footer itself - `.footer div div ul {}` would also work, or beter yet `.footer > div > div > ul {}` and the best thing would be to just add a class directly to the ul

Comment: Thanks for the help guys ... ummm ... tried everything thats been suggested. 

Forcing its not working, and neither's targeting the child elements with the '>' symbol... 

When ever ive made the alterations the CSS style isn't being picked up by chrome's devloper tools but when i make alterations else where they are... 

suspect a bug somewhere?

Comment: @scriptmonkey try to refresh the page, maybe it is using the cached css file, also - is the style not showing at all in the developer tools, or is it just crossed?

Comment: Update: i dont know wtf (<-- thats a technical term) is going on or why but when i move the declaration to the top of the form it works... ive sifted through the code upteen times and only been able to spot one rouge semi-colon missing which was rectified hours and hours ago... thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @pOcHa, im constantly refreshing and it picks up other style changes but in the devloper tools its not even registering as being styled.

as i just mentioned when i move the declaration to the top of the sheet it works but i dont understand why (which is a dangerous way to get something working)

Comment: @scriptmonkey you would have to post your whole page, or better yet make a jsfiddle

Comment: just lost my jsfiddle virginity... i hope this is correct http://jsfiddle.net/qXVej/

Comment: @scriptmonkey it displays fine for me, and i don't see your `.footer ul` class anywhere (mind the dot before the footer) - what **is** the problem here

Comment: Sorry i tried to style the footer by naming a class and styling that but in lieu of it not working i removed it... 

I seem to of found something of what the issue is... The footer styles are only defined when i put them above the "nav h1 { ... }" css style... below that they dont work?

however the other styles are working?

Answer (score 0):

Your example definitely references the Unordered List without issue, both examples in fact. Perhaps you have other conflicting styles which are giving you the issue?

To see it working [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/m_raffaele/MtDHz/). *Please notice that I have put a red border around it to help make it clearer.*

Comment: well if i just straight link you the website: http://www.virtualharrogate.com ... maybe a fresh set of eyes might be beneficial... dont worry teh page isnt to code heavy... but what you've depicted is what id expect

Comment: Sorry, I just had a chance to look now but your link doesn't seem to be working?